# Reverse AJAX? Can data changes be 'PUSHED' to script?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, server-side, server-push

I have noticed that some of my ajax-heavy sites (ones I visit, not ones I have built), have certain auto-refresh features. For example, in GMail, if I get a new message, I see the new message without a page reload. It's the same with the Facebook browser-based IM client. From what I can tell, there aren't any java applets handling the server-browser binding, so I'm left to assume it's being done by AJAX and perhaps some element I'm unaware of. So by my best guess, it's done in one of two ways:

1. The javascript does a steady "ping" to a server-side script, checking for any updates that might be available (which would explain why some of these pages bring any other heavy-duty pages to a crawl). or
2. The javascript sits idly by and a server-side script actually "Pushes" any updates to the browser. But I'm not sure if this is possible. I'd imagine there is some kind of AJAX function that still pings, but all it simply asks "any updates?" and the server-script has a simple boolean that says "nope" or "I'm glad you asked."  But if this is the case, any data changes would need to call the script directly so that it has the data changes ready and makes the change to that boolean function.

So is that possible/feasible/how it works? I imagine something like:

Someone sends an email/IM/DB update to the server, the server calls the script using the script's URL plus some relevant GET variable, the script notes the change and updates the "updates available" variable, the AJAX gets the response that there are in fact updates, the AJAX runs its normal "update page" functions, which executes the normal update scripts and outputs them to the browser.

I ask because it seems really inefficient that the js is just doing a constant check which requires a) the server to do work every 1.5 seconds, and b) my browser to do work every 1.5 seconds just so that on my end I can say "Oh boy, I got an IM! just like a real IM client!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Comment: Wow, I even used the same catchphrases. that's almost embarrassing. But my initial search on how to do this in PHP mentions infinite loop scripts. Does an infinite loop have to take place somewhere along the line for this type of thing to work? Why can't the actual changed datasource (IMAP server, DB, txt file, whatever) trigger the script to wake up and handle things?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually been working on a small .NET Web App that uses the Ajax with long polling technique described.

Depending on what technology you're using, you could use thread signaling mechanisms to hold your request until an update is retrieved.
With ASP.NET I'm running my server on a single machine, so I store a reference to my Producer object (which contains a thread that processes the data). To initiate the data pull, my service's Subscribe method is called, which creates a Consumer object that's registered with the Producer. If the Consumer is long polling mode, it has a AutoResetEvent which is signaled whenever it receives new data, and whenever the web client makes a request for data, the Consumer first waits on the reset event, and then returns it.

But you're mentioning something about PHP - as far as I know persistence is maintained through serialization, not actually keeping the object in memory, so I don't know how you could reference a Producer object using $_CACHE[] or $_SESSION[]. When I developed in PHP I never really knew anything about multithreading so I didn't play around with it, but I guess you can look into that.

Using infinite loops is going to consume a lot of your processing power - I would exhaust all other options first.